# how to make validation while filtering according to date and time?

Tags: laravel

I am adding from and to format in filtering in laravel but it accepts later from and before to how to manage this?
 image is like https://prnt.sc/qjv17s

Comment: do u need validation.?

Comment: show me your query ?

Comment: i need to make sure that filter doesnot accept 'to' earlier than 'from' while filtering

Comment: $purchase = Purchase::with('raw_material')->where('company_id', $company_id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->whereBetween('date_of_purchase', array($request->from, $request->to))->paginate(1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of built-in Laravel validation rules for date comparison.

1. [before:date](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-before)

```php
'from' => 'required|date|before:to'
```

2. [after:date](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-after)

```php
'to' => 'required|date|after:from'
```

Comment: how to make date to insert only after today

Comment: use `date|after:today` as your validation rule for the respective attribute

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has built in validation 
`before:date` try this

```php
 $this->validate($request,[
            'from' => 'required|before:date',
        ]);


        $purchase = Purchase::with('raw_material')
        ->where('company_id', $company_id)
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->whereBetween('date_of_purchase', array($request->from, $request->to))-
        >paginate(1);
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-before